# Can I export a grouped DataFrame to a file?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a 1.2 million rows DataFrame that I grouped by a column and taken de count values of another column in pandas:

```
df_2 = df['ColumnA'].groupby(df['ColumnB']).value_counts()
```

The result is what I expect, with a length of +20K. Is there a way to export that into an Excel file? I used `pd.to_excel` but that created a file with the value count of ColumnB, so I lost the original text found in ColumnB and the categories of the groupby function.

What I am looking for is a way to export the way the grouped DataFrame looks.

Example of `df`:

```
     USDvalue     Category     Text      ...
0    1            red          jacket
1    1.2          blue         pillow
2    2.2          grey         horse
3    3            yellow       table
...
1282597 rows × 11 columns
```

To create `df_2`:

```
df_2 = df['Text'].groupby(df['Category']).value_counts()
```

Example of `df_2`:

```
Category     Text
red          jacket       10
             pants         9
             dress         5
blue         pillow       20
             blanket       8
             cover         3
grey         horse         5
             cat           2
             dog           1

Name: text, Length: 20910, dtype: int64
```

I would like to export df2 to an Excel file with the same 'look'. Meaning that the output file should look like the output of df_2. [This is the output I file I get when using pd.to_excel](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1K2AA6YMy6XYrlIpsi9UtV67d3Lcuya67OzF5n8Nd99k/edit?usp=sharing).

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you provide a sample of `df` and an example of what you want `df_2` to look like when you export it to excel?

Comment: @Oscar The dataframe has an index that isn't getting printed, are you using `index=False` as an argument in the `to_excel` method ?

Comment: @tidakdiinginkan Yes I am, and I still get the same result a column named Text with the values, not the actual text or the categories as columns 1 and 2. But it does keep the order of the values/categories, meaning the values decrease to 1 and then when a new category start there's a higher number. I'll search if there's a way to attach to my post the output excel file I get.

Comment: what does the output look like if you were to remove `index=False`?

Comment: You could replace the value_counts() by this - `df_3 = df.groupby(['Category', 'Text'], as_index=False).count()`, since this returns a `df` whereas `value_counts()` returns a Series object.

Comment: @tidakdiinginkan that worked, such a simple fix! I don't really understand why, thanks!

Comment: While writing to excel, if you say `index=False`, you are telling it to exclude them. You should identify the `columns` and `indexes` in your dataframe prior to writing

Comment: @tidakdiinginkan I tried it to see what it looked like. And it made the new df_3 look weird. Plus I don't have the count as a value of each text that has repeated over the column. But your previous comment solved my issue.

Answer (score 0):

The answer was given by @tidakdiinginkan in the comments below the question:

Remove `index=False`in `pd.to_excel`.

This was his response:

While writing to excel, if you say `index=False`, you are telling it to exclude them. You should identify the `columns` and `indexes` in your dataframe prior to writing